# Complexity of Balloon Sort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I've been looking up for the complexity of balloon sort but I haven't seen anything about it on the internet. Can someone give me the average-case, best-case and worst-case of balloon sort? We're conducting research on it and we really need it to finish our thesis.

Comment: You couldn't have searched... at all. There's just no way. http://bigocheatsheet.com/ First google result.

Comment: You can find more information here http://www.glennvon.com/2010/10/balloon-sorting-in-c.html?m=1

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal It doesn't provide the information I need but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like O(n^2) to me.  You have

```
for(x=0;x<num;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<num-x;y++){ 
        if(N[x] > N[x+y]){ 
        temp=N[x];
        N[x] =N[x+y];
        N[x+y]=temp;
    }
}
```

You have n for the first loop.

For the second loop, when x = 0, the loop runs another n times (this is the worst case).  Therefore you have n*n = n^2

It looks like the other loops are only O(n), so the O(n^2) controls the running time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the best case would be O(n) and the average case is O(n^2)?

Comment: @Levi, O(n) and O(n^2) *what*?  Operations? Comparisons? Swaps?

Comment: Overall, the loop nest called out in this answer always performs *exactly* num + (num - 1) + (num - 2) + ... + 1 = num * (num + 1) / 2 = O(n^2) comparisons.  That's best-, worst-, and average case.

Comment: Yes, like John said, all cases have O(n^2) running time. i.e. best, worst, and average case.  This is because the two for loops are always executed based on the value of num.  There are no cases, e.g. if else that control how many times it loops, so it will always execute both loops.